# OpenBSD boot hangs after “256 targets”

Tags: boot, openbsd, amd, asus

I'm trying to boot OpenBSD 7.4 on my desktop with ASUS B650E-i motherboard, but after `scsibus3 at softraid0: 256 targets`, it hangs. Is OpenBSD incompatible with hardware this recent?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's not hung.  That's the point at which the the kernel switches to the DRM driver for the video output (not X11, though, that's something else).

More info is needed for people to be able to help you. If you configured the network properly when running the installer, and if indeed it isn't hung, you can SSH into the machine and get a complete `dmesg`, which would give details about the video driver, and whether it loaded properly.  Send an email along with its contents to `misc@openbsd.org` to get some help.

In the meantime, do you see a `radeondrm0` line at some point?  You can try disabling it by entering `boot -c` at the boot prompt, then `disable radeondrm`, and `exit` to continue booting.  If then you can see the entire boot process, then you found your culprit.